# Sencha cmd build : specify 2 --destinations

Tags: maven, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am calling the following as part of a Maven build to generate my ExtJS project resources

```
sencha app build --destination "some path"
```

There is a requirement to copy the generated resource files into 2 locations within the project. Ideally I could specify 2 paths like this

```
sencha app build --destination "first path" "second path"
```

This is not working nor is specifying the --destination argument before each path.

I could use a symlink to copy contents of first path into second but this could get complicated when working on branches where the symlink is not defined.

I looked into the Maven resources plugin: copy-resources but it starts copying the files before the Sencha build has finished. How can I make this plugin wait until the build has finished ?

Any other suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by changing the phase element value to 'package'. It now waits until the sencha build is complete before copying resources

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-appCtx</id>
                    **<phase>package</phase>**
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/</outputDirectory>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/othersrc/</directory>
                                 <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                 </includes>                                    
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```